What is the latex code for this symbol?
An open circle with a tilde symbol in it:


How do you want to use it (math, text, picture)? Has it to be the same or just similar (like \CircNgt of logix)? Have you looked at: How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?
